# Compacting gravel on top of landscape fabric

Tags: gravel, landscape

I am planning to use a plate compactor to compact some #57 gravel that is on top of a landscape fabric. My question:

- Will this break the landscape fabric or reduce its functionality, or this type of fabric is able to hold the power of a plate compactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#57 can be rolled or lightly vibrated / tampered to help settle, and you can do that with landscape fabric underneath. You do not need to compact it.

Yes, compacting with a plate vibrator may cause ruptures in the fabric, depending on how angular your specific gravel is and the quality/thickness of the fabric. It might fail, or you might succeed, but the benefit of plate vibrating is likely minimal.

It is better to firmly compact the substrate fill first, apply the fabric, then spread and roll or tamper the gravel.

Comment: By tamper, you mean manual tamper, right?

Comment: @Nobita yes, they have a 8x8in 10lbs pad, and a 48in handle, or anything similar you DIY

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of fabric it is and also what is below it.  If it is smooth and not sitting on numerous sharp edges and protrusions etc.

And that determins what will be.

Also here is part of the know if you will and it pertains to the whole thing.

#57 gravel can only compact roughly 1 inch.

With or without compaction, it will compact itself in just a matter of time.  In other words what will happen will happen if things have been laid down and the gravel already spread and in place.

And there you have it.

You take care.